# Download large files using React and AspnetCore to open browser save (headers)

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, download, http-headers

I'm struggling with the problem of downloading large files using a web API in asp net core and frontend in React.

When the file starts downloading it doesn't show the dialog browser (Save As File Dialog) until it downloads the file in memory and next gives the possibility to save it.

When the file is bigger, like 200MB, the user can't choose where to save the file before start downloading it and see the download progress in the browser tab.

This is to use with react frontend and web API in aspnet core.
After reading for some hours I couldn't find the solution.
I can't use a link to download the file because I need to authenticate with a token.

Maybe I am missing any configuration or setup in my backend/frontend?

Any suggestions or advice will be very appreciated.

The method of my web api:

```
        [HttpGet("{fileName}")]
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult GetFile(string fileName)
        {

            Stream stream = _fileManager.GetFileContent(fileName);
            // Response...
            ContentDisposition cd = new ContentDisposition("attachment")
            {
                FileName = fileName,
                // DispositionType = "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";",
                Inline = false // false = prompt the user for downloading;  true = browser to try to show the file inline
            };

            Response.Headers.Add(HeaderNames.ContentDisposition, cd.ToString());

            return File(stream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
        }
```

The frontend using axios to get it.

```js
async function Download() {
  var authToken = await authService.Token();

  console.log("calling request", process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "files/GetFile/iPro.zip");
  if (authToken) {
    BioAxios.get("/files/GetFile/file.zip", {
      responseType: "blob",

      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer ".concat(authToken.access_token),
        "Content-Type": "application/zip"
      }
    }).then(response => {
      // Log somewhat to show that the browser actually exposes the custom HTTP header
      console.log("Full Response", response);

      // Let the user save the file.
      FileSaver.saveAs(response.data, "file.zip");
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're dealing with large size file downloading, I think the most easiest way is to configure an `OnMessageReceived` for `JwtBearerEvents` such that you can use a native anchor by `<a href="/files/GetFile/file.zip?access_token={token}"> download </a>`.

Comment: I will take a look to this option, thanks for your answer!